# show/hide elements inside of for loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following:

```
<div v-for="num in [1,2,3,4,5]" :key="num ">
    <customelement0 :num ="num" />
    <span @click="show = !show" > Details: </span>
    <customelement1 v-if="show" :num ="num" />
    <hr />
</div>
```

and:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      show: false
    };
  },
};
```

However, in this implementation Whenever `show` changes it affects all of the `customelement1`s and will show/hide all of them.

How would one solve this problem, so that whenever a user clicks on the `span` it only shows/hides one element in the loop?

P.S.: in reality, the length of the loop is much longer, than what's indicated above

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is essentially that your `show` is a variable for the entire component, and isn't linked to one of your array elements.
Generally, we don't really tend to hard-code an array into the html, but rather in the `data`, as shown in the other answers.

The other answers show it with `num` being coded into the object but you could also do something like this. Note that `other` field is optional and not required. The main advantage of this method is that you don't need to code every number.

```html
<div v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">
    <!-- Note I do i+1 so that it matches the 1,2,3 in your example -->
    <!-- if you're okay with having 0,1,2 you can omit the +1 -->
    <customelement0 :num="i+1" />
    <span @click="item.show = !item.show" >Details: </span>
    <customelement1 v-if="item.show" :num="i+1" />
    <hr />
</div>
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        {show: false, other: "foo"},
        {show: false, other: "bar"},
        //...
      ],
    };
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change number to object and toggle property:

```html
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="todo in todos">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
          v-on:change="toggle(todo)"
          v-bind:checked="todo.done">

        <del v-if="todo.done">
          {{ todo.text }}
        </del>
        <span v-else>
          {{ todo.text }}
        </span>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
      { text: "1", done: false },
      { text: "2", done: false },
      { text: "3", done: true },
      { text: "4", done: true },
      { text: "5", done: true },
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can to save the value `isShow` for each element in the array. So you need to use an array of objects in you data and do something like this:

```js
export default {
 data() {
   return {
     numList: [
        {
           num: 1,
           isShow: true
        },
        {
           num: 2,
           isShow: true
        }
     ]
   };
 },
};
```

In your template:

```html
<div v-for="item in numList" :key="item.num">
    <customelement0 :num="item.num" />
    <span @click="item.isShow = !item.isShow" > Details: </span>
    <customelement1 v-if="item.isShow" :num="item.num" />
    <hr />
</div>
```